# sed ’s/ \([0-9]\)\/\([0-9]\) / \2\/\1 /’ filename

Tags: sed

Can I know what does the below code mean?

`sed 's/ \([0-9]\)\/\([0-9]\) / \2\/\1 /' filename`

Thanks

Comment: you mean if I input " 12 " this will return " 21 "?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 4):

`sed 's/ \([0-9]\)\/\([0-9]\) / \2\/\1 /' filename` would be code valid in most Unix shells.

In shells, the space character is used to delimit token in its syntax, and `'...'` is used to *quote*/*escape* strings which for the shell means *remove the special meaning of characters*. In that case that means the space and backslash characters inside `'...'` are not treated specially be the shell.

The first word being `sed` which is not a keyword in the shell syntax, the shell will interpret that line as a simple command invocation. I will fork  look up the `sed` command in `$PATH` and execute the first one it finds in a child process with `sed`, `s/ \([0-9]\)\/\([0-9]\) / \2\/\1 /` and `filename` as arguments.

`sed` itself is an interpreter for another language, the `sed` language.

Unless passed a script by way of the `-e` or `-f` options, the first non-option argument that `sed` receives is considered as the script for it to interpret.

Here, that's `s/ \([0-9]\)\/\([0-9]\) / \2\/\1 /`.

`sed` processes its input (here coming from the `filename` file) one line at a time (with the current line loaded into `sed`'s pattern space), and for each line, interprets the code in the provided script and prints the resulting pattern space on stdout.

Here, that script is made of one and only one `sed` command: the `s`ubstitute command.

Its syntax is `s%pattern%replacement%flags` where any character¹ can be used in place of `%`.

Here the author used `/` in place of `%`. That's the most commonly used but here it was a poor choice as `/` happens to be used in both the pattern and replacement, so it had to be escaped with `\`.

So the pattern is `" \([0-9]\)/\([0-9]\) "`. In `sed`, patterns are *basic regular expressions* (BRE). In BRE:

- SPC, `/` matches themselves as they are not special
- `[set]` matches one *collating element* in the specified set. When that set contains `x-y`, it matches collating elements that sort between `x` and `y`. For `0-9`, that includes at least the 0123456789 characters, but possibly  more depending on the locale, OS and `sed` implementation..
- `\(...\)` is used for grouping and also for *capturing*. That is, what is being matched by what's inside will be *captured* and made available in the *replacement* as `\1` for the first capture group, `\2` for the second, etc.

The replacement here is `" \2/\1 "`, where `\2` and `\1` are what was matched by the first 2 capture groups in the pattern.

In your case, the list of flags is empty, and in particular since the `g` (for `g`lobal) flag is not supplied, only the first match will be substituted on each line.

So here, it means that it replaces at most one `<SPC><a-digit><slash><another-digit><SPC>` with `<SPC><another-digit><slash><a-digit><SPC>` on each line within `filename` and outputs the result on stdout.

So for instance, with a `filename` that contains:

```
a 1/2 b 3/4
test
c4/5 6/7 d
```

It will output:

```
a 2/1 b 3/4
test
c4/5 7/6 d
```

---

<sup>¹ except backslash and newline and with several `sed` implementations multibyte characters. You'll also want to avoid non-ASCII characters, and if you need the pattern or replacement to include non-ASCII characters, characters whose encoding is not found in other characters which in practice leaves only `!"#$%&' ()*+,-./:;<=>?` if we also exclude ASCII control characters.</sup>